# What is meant by term in brackets for cmake command?

Tags: cmake

What's meant in the line (https://scipopt.org/doc/html/CMAKE.php)

`cmake .. [-DSOPLEX_DIR=/path/to/soplex]`

What to put as  `[-DSOPLEX_DIR=/path/to/soplex]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Square brackets denote optional arguments. In other words, you could use the argument `-DSOPLEX_DIR=/path/to/soplex`, or you could omit it.